# Belief Propagation on MRF with complex cliques

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, machine-learning, markov-chains

Is there a belief propagation algorithm for exact inference on a MRF with complex clique structures (i.e. ones involving more than 2 neighbours)?

For MRF's with cliques that only involve pairwise interaction, you could just search out far enough and cluster to form an acyclic graph and run the usual BP. With more complex cliques, this seems impossible to me as clustering might involve cutting through a clique with multiple members on either side. Is there a workaround for this? Perhaps some clever conditioning arguments?